# Import JS and CSS in htmls

Tags: node.js, web

I'm new to web development and can't seem to understand this. My Node.js project has the following structure -

```
public - 
       |-js-
           |-a.js

       |-css-
            |-a.css

       |-htmls-
            |-a.html
```

I have set up the static middleware to the public folder.

```
webServer.use(express.static('public'))
```

Why do I have to do something like this to include a.js in a.html

```
<script src="../js/a.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="js/a.js"></script> ?
```

since I have set up routes that the static content be served from the public folder?
How does the request for a.js goes to my server?

If I do something like this -

```
public - 
       |-js-
           |-a.js

       |-css-
            |-a.css

       |-htmls-
            |-a.html
src - 
    |-views-
           |-b.html
```

In my b.html i am able to use the a.js by just using

```
<script src="js/todo.js"></script>
```

Why is this?

EDIT- I am serving my b.html file using something like this -

```
webServer("/todo", function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/views/b.html')
})
```

Comment: Apparently you're not familiar with directory structures. Maybe you should review [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files)?

Comment: @BryndenBielefeld But then why in my b.html I dont have to do something like ../../public/js/a.js ?

Comment: The URLs are loaded relative to the URL of the .html page that is including them by the browser, not the server. So if you are viewing `/htmls/a.html` then you need to move back one directory first to get to `js` or `css`. When you want to view `b.html` you have a route set up so that the browser just navigates to `/todo` without `/views` in there, so from the browser's perspective it can just move forward into `js/` without moving back a directory.